# Knockout JS call function in selectedOptions attribute

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I got the following:

```
<select data-bind="options: infoLogMessages, selectedOptions: setCurrentInfoLogMessage"></select>
```

I have a view model which looks like:

```
var InfoLogFilterVM = function () {
    this.propertyChangeSupport = new KnockoutPropertyChangeSupport(this);

    this.currentInfoLogMessage = ko.observable();
    this.infoLogMessages = ko.observableArray();
}

InfoLogFilterVM.prototype = (function() {
return {
    PROP_CURRENTINFOLOGMESSAGE: "currentInfoLogMessage",
    PROP_INFOLOGMESSAGES: "infoLogMessages",

    addPropertyChangeListener: function(listener) {
        this.propertyChangeSupport.addListener(listener);
    },

    removePropertyChangeListener: function(listener) {
        this.propertyChangeSupport.removeListener(listener);
    },

    setCurrentInfoLogMessage: function(currentInfoLogMessage) {
        var oldValue = this.currentInfoLogMessage();
        this.currentInfoLogMessage(currentInfoLogMessage);
        this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChangeEvent(this.PROP_CURRENTINFOLOGMESSAGE, oldValue, currentInfoLogMessage);
    },

    getCurrentInfoLogMessage: function() {
        return this.currentInfoLogMessage();
    },

    setInfoLogMessages: function(infoLogMessages) {
        var oldValue = this.infoLogMessages();
        this.infoLogMessages(infoLogMessages);
        this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChangeEvent(this.PROP_INFOLOGMESSAGES, oldValue, infoLogMessages);
    },

    getInfoLogMessages: function () {
        return this.infoLogMessages();
    },
}
}());
```

I wish to call the setCurrentInfoLogMessage function in the view model so I can fire a property change event, which means that I am not interested in calling currentInfoLogMessage property directly like this:

```
selectedOptions: currentInfoLogMessage
```

I have tried to change selectedOptions to

```
value: setCurrentInfoLogMessage
```

I have also tried to do something like:

```
selectedOptions: function (_infoLogMessage) { setCurrentInfoLogMessage(_infoLogMessage) }
```

but nothing works.

Is there actually a way of calling a custom function within the data-bind attribute with selectedOptions or value attribute?

Comment: you just need to subscribe to the `setCurrentInfoLogMessage` there is a change you will be notified is this what you looking for

Comment: Since I want to call the setCurrentInfoLogMessage function directly to not surpass additional function calls this is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'd reconsider your approach.  Work with knockout instead of around it.  In the places where you're listening for whatever `firePropertyChangeEvent` runs, instead [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the observable.  If you don't want to/can't do that, at least do it within `InfoLogFilterVM` directly, and have that subscription do the work of `setCurrentInfoLogMessage`.

Comment: Yes I am currently thinking of having this approach. However, would be more convenient in this case to actually call the setCurrentInfoLogMessage function directly.

If there is a way of actually calling setCurrentInfoLogMessage function directly, I am appreciating an answer which points this way :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, I'd recommend approaching this from a different way.  That said, what you want can be achieved with the use of [writable computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html):

```
var _logMessageValue = ko.observable();
this.currentInfoLogMessage = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () {
        return this._logMessageValue();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        var oldValue = this._logMessageValue();
        this._logMessageValue(value);
        this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChangeEvent(this.PROP_CURRENTINFOLOGMESSAGE, oldValue, value);               
    },
    owner: this
});
```